# Setting notebook height in Python Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I used `fill=BOTH` property on Tkinter notebook page but it only fill width of the main frame and not the height of the frame.

```
note.pack(fill=BOTH)
```

Why is this happening?

```
import Tkinter
import tkMessageBox
from Tkinter import *
import ttk
from ttk import *

app = Tk()
app.configure(background='DimGray')
app.geometry('600x600')
app.resizable(width=False, height=False)

note = Notebook(app)

tab1 = Frame(note)
tab2 = Frame(note)
tab3 = Frame(note)

note.add(tab1, text = "Summary", compound=TOP)
note.add(tab2, text = "Details")
note.add(tab3, text = "Up Comming")
note.pack(fill=BOTH)

app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The height is determined by the frames packed inside. Since you have nothing inside, the height is 0. You can tell pack to expand to the available space if you want to override that:

```
note.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=True)
```